# Which is the better way to select the last entry row from a table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, query, execution-plan, postgresql-9.6

I need to test an attribute from the last entry row from a table to trigger a trigger function on PostgreSQL 9.6. Just below, there is a little piece of my table.
It's doesn't have a timestamp column, wasn't created using WITH OIDS and the commit timestamp tracking property from postgres.conf isn't turned on and won't be.

| idinsumo | flagimport | active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| uuid | integer | integer |

So, I've tried two queries, the first one:

```
SELECT idinsumo FROM tablename 
WHERE CTID = (SELECT MAX(CTID) FROM recurso);
```

and this returned me the last entry, but looking into the documentation, it says:

> The physical location of the row version within its table. Note that although the ctid can be used to locate the row version very quickly, a row's ctid will change if it is updated or moved by VACUUM FULL. Therefore ctid is useless as a long-term row identifier. The OID, or even better a user-defined serial number, should be used to identify logical rows.

So, the first one isn't an option. Following to the second one:

```
SELECT idinsumo 
FROM tablename 
    OFFSET (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename ) - 1)
```

and it's not returned me the last entry row. And it was terrified me, so I used the EXPLAIN to see the query plan.

```
    InitPlan 1 (returns $0)  
     -> Aggregate  (cost=100.06..100.07 rows=1 width=8)  
      -> Index Only Scan using recurso_pkey on recurso recurso_1  (cost=0.28..95.52 rows=1816 width=0)  
    -> Index Only Scan using recurso_pkey on recurso  (cost=0.28..95.52 rows=1816 width=16)
```

As you can see PostgreSQL it's using the pkey column(that is a uuid column) to index the query and doesn't return the last entry. But if I do:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename 
    OFFSET (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename ) - 1)
```

It works. Finally, there is another way to do this query?

Comment: There is no such thing as the "last row" unless you have something you can sort the rows by. So without an `order by` the concept of a "last row" makes no sense. And the `ctid` does **not** impose any chronological order. It will change with every UPDATE of the row. As none of your queries includes an `order by` you can essentially also simply do `select * from tablename limit 1`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, it's made all sense, but it's an old DB and I'm new at the project. I'm fighting hard to implement commit timestamp tracking or include a timestamp column, but I'm outvoted.
In your opinion what is the better way, a commit timestamp tracking or a user-defined timestamp column?